# How to automatically offset many keyframes in a sequential order?

Tags: animation, keyframes

Is there a way to automatically sequence hundreds of keyframes?
[image]

Comment: search for free commotion add-on, it does exactly that

Comment: Thank you very much, it does exactly what I needed